# Difficult passage in Valery

Tags: poésie

In La Jeune Parque we find the line

> Souffle au masque la pourpre imprégnant le refus
> D’être moi-même en flamme une autre que je fus

This was translated as:

> Blow through this mask the scarlet of refusing
> To be again another one I was

So the translator ignored 'en flamme'.  I'm guessing "D'être moi-même en flamme' would be translated as 'to be myself in flames'.  But I'm still having trouble relating 'to be myself in flames' to 'une autre que je fus'.

He also ignored 'imprégant' but I think 'the pregnant scarlet' works.  Also I don't see how 'le refus' can be a genitive of mask.  Isn't it the direct object of 'souffle'?  However, if 'le refus' is a direct object then I'm stuck with the problem of what 'la pourpre' is since it is also a candidate for being the object of 'souffle'.

So perhaps 'le refus' and 'la pourpre' are both direct objects and they are in apposition to one another, though if that were the case I would think there would have to be a comma after 'imprégant'.  Still, I'm going to put my money on the following translation:

Blow through this mask the pregnant scarlet, the refusal to be one's self in flames, the other that I was.

Comment: If it makes you feel better, I checked the original stanza and it is just as impenetrable to an untrained native speaker :) My best guess is that "la pourpre" is the object of "souffle" and "le refus" the object of "imprégnant". Also, *"imprégner" un refus* is most likely the key to understanding it all... and it's metaphorical beyond recognition to me.

Comment: This is beside the point, but let me say that I really admire this translator. Very often, when translators run across incomprehensible sections of poems they translate them literally. Here, Alistair Elliot has enough courage to avoid doing that.

Comment: I agree with Shor.  I almost wrote some words along the lines of I have no issues with Elliot, he's trying to translate the text into iambic pentameter and when you do that, of course, you're going to have to depart from the original.

Comment: @guillaume31, that's a good idea, 'impregnant' would be a present participle whose object is 'le refus'.

Comment: One more comment, *en flamme* quite possibly refers to *bûcher* in the previous line, *Souvenir, ô bûcher, dont le vent d'or m'affronte*. So *souffle* would then be an imperative with the subject *souvenir* (*memory*).

Comment: Looking online, lots of versions have a period after *m'affronte*, but [the original](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/ad/Val%C3%A9ry_-_%C5%92uvres_de_Paul_Valery%2C_Vol_3%2C_1933.djvu/page73-1078px-Val%C3%A9ry_-_%C5%92uvres_de_Paul_Valery%2C_Vol_3%2C_1933.djvu.jpg) had a comma, which I think makes it very likely that *souffle* is an imperative addressing *souvenir*.

Comment: *O pyre whose air of gold confronts me, breathe on this mask the scarlet that empowers the refusal to be within my burning self some other than I was.*

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate that, that makes perfect sense

Comment: @LukeSawczak very nice one, although LPH's answer would make it "pervades"/"imbues" the refusal rather than "empowers"?

Comment: @guillaume31 It was a hard choice for the stress pattern of that phrase, but there probably is a better option than "empowers". I don't think "pervading" the refusal makes much sense in English, though; I take the metaphor of impregnate here to be more like "gives weight to, gives substance to". Would you say that's a valid reading?

Comment: @LukeSawczak well as I said in another comment, it's a very tangible phenomenon (blushing/flushing) colliding with an abstract feeling, so hard to come up with an appropriate verb. I read "la pourpre imprègne" as "the scarlet diffuses/spreads/pours out through/pervades" but I might be wrong in my interpretation of the metaphor.

Comment: @guillaume31 But what does it spread throughout or pervade? Le refus ; and a refusal is a thing to be bolstered or given the lie to, given a certain quality or denied it, but it doesn't seem like an étendue or expansive thing that another can "pervade"... P.S. this question has prompted me to work on a prose translation of the poem, so I'll come up against the line again later with more context :)

Comment: @LukeSawczak if you come up with a prose translation of the poem I'd be happy to read it. Please let me know how I can get in touch with you to find out if you've finished it.  Alternatively, my email is bobsmith76 at mail dot com

Comment: @LukeSawczak it spreads throughout the cold mask of refusal that her face had been displaying so far. At least that's how I understand it (also see LPH's answer below). That's "imprégner" in a literal sense and I can't think of another figurative meaning that would fit. "Rougir la pâle circonstance" and "consumer ce don décoloré" further down are similar.

Comment: What does not add up is this conclusion that the tortured soul should be exhorting the "wind" of shame to redden even more his/her face; as I understand these lines, we are not dealing with an exhortation but with a lamentation, and the comma ("m'affronte,") is an asyndetic coordination: the wind only can blow, but if the tortured soul where addressing the wind (exhortation), there would have to be a term of address; there is none: "wind" appears in a relative.  @LukeSawczak "Le refus" can't be seen as a simple no; instead it (1/2)

Comment: must be conceived as a thinking process during which the pros and cons are being weighed, and each examination of fact, because it results in a negative judgement, is cause for shame, and thus follows the metaphor of the reddish hue as the shame pervading or impregnating the refusal. (2/2)

Comment: @LPH "ô bûcher", "Souffle", "Viens", "[que] rejaillisse", etc. seem unambiguously imperative to me though...

Comment: @guillaume31 There is no doubt about "viens" as "mon sang" is being addressed, this is an imperative. There is in that part this contradictory acceptation, what could be called a morbid relish in the guilt felt; but then if this were the case  for the part beginning with "souffle" the subject of "souffle" would be "souvenir" or "bûcher" and that hardly makes any sense.

Comment: I read the physical situation here as simply the heat of the pyre giving a flushed (red) appearance; but a flush is not the same as a blush, and doesn't have to represent shame, but simply any strong emotion, even anger or indignation. The emotionlessness of the "mask" might belie what ought to be a passionate refusal, so Parque asks the fire to lend force to the refusal (hence my leaning towards "empower") by reddening her face. It might be too bold / paradoxical, but I wonder if the idea is that, rather than this girlish *rose*, the fire might grant a forceful *pourpre*.

Comment: @LPH It's clear that *le vent* is not the subject of anything but *m'affronte* syntactically, but by transposition is the agency by which the *bûcher* (the actual vocative subject of *souffle* in this reading) would blow.

Comment: @LPH I side with Luke on the grammatical bit. If *souvenir* is not the subject of *souffle*, what is it the subject of? What is its function in the text? It being subject of an imperative sentence is also similar and semantically coherent with "Viens, mon sang, viens rougir", "viens consumer". IMO the Parque is wishing for that heat to come invade her and fight the cold mask of refusal - is where I differ from Luke.

Answer (score 3):

Osera-t-il, le Temps, de mes diverses tombes,
Ressusciter un soir favori des colombes,
Un soir qui traîne au fil d’un lambeau voyageur
De ma docile enfance un reflet de rougeur,
Et trempe à l’émeraude un long rose de honte ?
Souvenir, ô bûcher, dont le vent d’or m’affronte,
Souffle au masque la pourpre imprégnant le refus
D’être en moi-même en flamme une autre que je fus…
Viens, mon sang, viens rougir la pâle circonstance
Qu’ennoblissait l’azur de la sainte distance,
Et l’insensible iris du temps que j’adorai !
Viens consumer sur moi ce don décoloré
Viens ! que je reconnaisse et que je les haïsse,
Cette ombrageuse enfant, ce silence complice,
Ce trouble transparent qui baigne dans les bois…
Et de mon sein glacé rejaillisse la voix
Que j’ignorais si rauque et d’amour si voilée…
Le col charmant cherchant la chasseresse ailée.

There is very apparently an error in the translation of "masque". This word means plainly "the expression of the face". Otherwise, where would this supposed mask find a materialization in the text?

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/masque)) b) Expression du visage caractéristique d'un personnage, d'un type de personnage ou de personnalité. Un personnage de haute stature (...) dont les traits énergiques évoquaient le masque de Bonaparte jeune (Martin du G.,Thib.,Été 14, 1936, p.337).Le masque de l'anxieux est l'antithèse du masque du sourire (Mounier,Traité caract.,1946, p.233)
> • ... il semblait (...) qu'il eût suffi au sang japonais de sa mère d'adoucir le masque d'abbé ascétique du vieux Gisors − masque dont une robe de chambre en poil de chameau, cette nuit, accentuait le caractère − pour en faire le visage de samouraï de son fils. Malraux,Cond. hum.,1933, p.208.

"Souffle au masque" means "gives to the facial expression a reddish hue". This hue is caused by the shame that is associated to the process of refusing the reality of a former self; however the author gives to it an abstract reality, it is shame itself and it pervades the ideas that embody the refusal of himself (intellectual identification of Valery with the parque, see below). "En moi-même en flamme" is a bloc, it is the consciousness tortured by the memory (souvenir, ô bûcher), this memory being the former "self" and all that it evokes, which insinuates itself for a place alongside the present "self", but which meets with rejection.

> [Chemins de traverse de la philosophie](https://cheminstraverse-philo.fr/philosophes/de-la-jeune-parque-a-lalbum-de-vers-anciens-et-vice-versa/) 
> […] Ces divers éléments indiquent plusieurs thèmes :
>
> – celui du temps et de la mémoire : tout se passe comme si Valéry, sous la pression de Gide et de Gallimard, cherchant un sujet pour son poème, n’en trouvait pas d’autre qu’un regard sur son passé, ce long temps qui le sépare de ses premiers vers et de la rupture radicale qu’il instaure à ce moment, avec la poésie. Valéry prend donc pour thématique cela même qu’on lui demande de faire : revenir sur ce qu’il a fait.
>
> On saisit mieux par là la formule fameuse : « […] j’ai trouvé après coup dans le poème fini quelque air d’…auto-biographie (intellectuelle, s’entend)». (Corr. VG, 448). Qu’est-ce à dire ? — Que La Jeune Parque commence quand Valéry se retourne sur ce qu’il fut et refait le cheminement de sa vie intellectuelle, c’est-à-dire non seulement récapitule un parcours mais aussi cherche à restituer, à travers le processus de l’écriture les phases d’une identité qui se cherche : « Qui pleure là […] si proche de moi-même…? » [1-3] : telle est l’autoréférence (« je me voyais me voir », [35] qui a pour caractéristique la boucle – « Un cercle, a dit Valéry de La Jeune Parque ; si j’avais pu, je l’aurais fermé. »[2] – et l’auto-application, c’est-à-dire la confusion entre le sujet définissant et l’objet à définir, entre moi écrivant la vie de cette Parque et cet autre moi-même qu’elle est. Psyché, ce premier titre envisagé, était excellent qui disait la vie de l’esprit et le miroir, le théâtre de la vie mentale et ses «étranges personnages»[3]. Il ne s’agit donc pas simplement, comme chez Raymond Roussel, d’une méthode, du « Comment j’ai écrit certains de mes livres », mais de l’aperception du moi lointain, perdu peut-être, par un Je, et de l’authentification de soi par l’œuvre. En d’autres termes la Jeune Parque. « sai[t] ce que voit [ son] regard disparu» [160] : l’Album de vers anciens ; mais elle ne le peut qu’en dépouillant « ses robes successives » [80], celles d’une « race naïve » [50], c’est-à-dire trop adhérente à ce qu’elle a fait.
>
> La Jeune Parque répond à la question : que faire de mon passé ? et se surprend à penser, interdite : qu’ai-je fait ? ![4] (au sens où on fait son bilan mais aussi au sens où on commet une faute (« Quel crime par moi-même ou sur moi consommé?» [27] Tel serait le fond du poème, mais le fond n’étant qu’une forme impure, c’est cette forme impure qui fait retour et vient hanter sous forme de souvenir le présent et ceci d’autant plus qu’il est dérogé à la ligne de conduite que l’on s’était fixée. À Gide, en juillet 1912 (Corr. VG, 426) Valéry écrit : « Faut-il monter sur un théâtre qui, après tout et en vérité, n’est pas le mien ? […] Publier ce que j’ai fait, est-ce pas consacrer l’abandon et la catastrophe de ce pour quoi j’avais abandonné ce que j’ai fait ? »
>
> D’où le thème de la faute et de la honte qui « est un grand sujet » (C, V, 97)). Et ici l’entremêlement de plusieurs niveaux, sensibles dans les vers 190 sq – en italiques dans beaucoup d’édition et en particulier dans la première – qui me semblent être le point de départ du poème, comme l’indiquent les trois feuillets datés de 1913 […]

Comment: Thanks, it does make sense that way. "Mask" can also have a similar meaning in English, see https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/mask_1 - 4.

Comment: The tricky part for me was that I somehow equated "le refus d'être une autre que je fus" with "le refus d'être une autre que [celle que] je fus" which conflicted with the overall meaning. Also "imprégner le refus" is an odd clash of a very physical verb and a very abstract notion, especially since Valéry goes on to reintroduce physicality inside the refusal itself with "en flamme".... complex interleaving of metaphor, bodily sensations and abstract sentiments here.